# Decomposition of symmetric powers of reduced regular representation modulo $p$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, modular-representation-theory

Let $\bar{\rho}$ denote the reduced regular representation of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ over a field of characteristic $p$. The representation $\mathrm{Sym}^k \bar{\rho}$ decomposes (for each $k$) as a sum of indecomposable representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p$. (Recall that the indecomposable representations of $\mathbb{Z}/p$ over a field of characteristic $p$ are classified via the Jordan decomposition, and are determined by a dimension between $1$ and $p$.)

The precise decomposition is claimed (without proof) in in Prop. 5.2.1 of Mike Hill's [thesis](http://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/34545). As I'm a little confused about the grading, I don't want to write it out here.

Does anyone have a reference with a proof of this decomposition?